# How to make the line to be closed, having points of it? (in array)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, loops

I have a problem, I need to make the line to be closed, for example:

I put into the console this:

```
 4
 0 0
 1 1
 1 0
 0 1
```

and it must return LIKE THIS:

```
 0 0
 0 1
 1 1
 1 0
```

NOT like this:

```
 0 0
 0 1
 1 0
 1 1
```

in other words:

I input the number of points, then I input coord_x and coord_y, then I need to sort them and also to make it closed

here is the code

```
 struct Point {
int coordX;
int coordY;
};


 for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfMasPoint; ++i) {
    Point temp = masPoint[i];
    bool is_Sorted = 0;
    int j = i;
    for (; j > 0; --j) {
        if (temp.coordX > masPoint[j - 1].coordX) {
            is_Sorted = 1;
        } else {
            if (temp.coordX < masPoint[j - 1].coordX) {
                masPoint[j] = masPoint[j - 1];
            } else {
                if (temp.coordY >= masPoint[j - 1].coordY) {
                    is_Sorted = 1;
                } else {
                    masPoint[j] = masPoint[j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        if (is_Sorted == 1)
            break;
    }
    masPoint[j] = temp;
}
```

it always returns this:

```
 0 0
 0 1
 1 0
 1 1
```

I need to make it closed...I don't know how

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Please give a definition of `to make it closed` that is not an official term and I can not make up what you are asking from the question

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev you see the last point must be in the beginning of the line, so it must have one of the points...if the beginning is 0 0, so the last must be 1 0 or 0 1, or 0 0

Comment: It seems like you want to build [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set of points

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev , no it is not, I need to make the end of the line nearer to the beginning, it is not convex hull, because I need to use ALL points (it is a line)

Comment: To "make it closed", you just need to repeat the first point again last, so that the line ends at the same place it started... Changing the order of the points will not "make it closed" - it will just result in different (poly-)lines that traverse the same set of points.